# How to write regular expressions in eclipse without compile time errors

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Eclipse keeps on indicating there is an error in my code when I write a regular expression.

For example,

```
String regex = "/\((.+)\)/";
```

This causes eclipse to warn with a red flag:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \' 
>   \ )

How do I change this?

Comment: You must escape backslashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape backslashes

```
String regex = "/\\((.+)\\)/";
```

if you want to put *backslash* within quotes you must use the escape sequence, `\\`, on the interior quotes to convey that it is part of the String literal and doesn't have any other special meaning

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape all backslashes, so special characters appear "double escaped" - once for the String, once for the regular expression.